Excel/Adobe need to take multiple hyperlinks into pdf doc
I am looking for a way to take multiple hyperlinks that lead to individual pdf docs and have all of them opened in one pdf doc rather than thousands of individual ones.
The data comes as an excel report with hyperlinks as one of the columns. I can manually place the data in adobe and right click on the links and append into the doc one by one but I am hoping there is a better way to do it.
HELP!
Tried macro code i found:
Sub OpenMultipleLinks()
    On Error Resume Next
    Set myRange = Application.Selection
    Set myRange = Application.InputBox("Range", "OpenMultipleLinks", myRange.Address, Type:=8)
    For Each oneLink In myRange.Hyperlinks
        oneLink.Follow
    Next
End Sub

did not work. would not run or downloaded each file as individual files.
